# Can't Shrink a .LDF file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have got an a partition that is 150GB
I also have Microsoft SQL server on that volume,
the problem is I got a couple different databases on that volume,
but I can't shrink the log files because there is no space left.

I tried right click on a DB /tasks/shrink/files & also database.

I get this error message.

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Shrink failed for Database 'cterm_across'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1617.0+((KJ_RTM_GDR).110422-1901+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Shrink+Database&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The transaction log for database 'cterm_across' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 9002)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1617&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=9002&LinkId=20476

How can I walk around this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How did you try to shrink the log file? What options did you use?How much of the log file is free? If you are using Full recovery mode, backup the log file before trying to shrink it. You can't delete log entries that haven't been backed up.

Comment: What recovery model your database is using? If "full recovery", have you created full backup lately?

Comment: Hello Panagiotis,

I have used  Shrink database - test
I checked -->
Reorganize files before releasing unused space. Selecting this option may affect performance.

Comment: Arvo How do I see the recovery model I use?

sorry I have less expereicen in SQL server.
it looks like the DB does a backup each day...

Comment: please tell us the output of this query: `SELECT d.recovery_model, d.recovery_model_desc, d.log_reuse_wait, d.log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name = 'cterm_across'`  - first two columns describe the recovery model

Comment: CeOnSql
Recovery_model 
1
recovery_model_desc
FULL
log_reuse_wait
2
log_reuse_wait_desc
LOG_BACKUP

Comment: thanks - please check my answer - hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
-- Do a Backup of your database - save it anywhere:
BACKUP DATABASE cterm_across TO DISK = N'C:\Temp\cterm_across.bak'

-- Do a Backup of the transaction log - save it anywhere:
BACKUP LOG cterm_across TO DISK = N'C:\Temp\cterm_across.bak'
-- If you want to truncate the transaction log: save the backup on null device:
--BACKUP LOG cterm_across TO DISK='NUL:'

-- Change recovery model to simple for the call of Shrinkfile
ALTER DATABASE cterm_across SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
DBCC SHRINKFILE(logical_name_of_your_logfile)
ALTER DATABASE cterm_across SET RECOVERY FULL
```

You just have to replace the logical_name_of_your_logfile with the correct logical file name. You can find them here: Rightclick on database - Properties - Files - The column `Logical Name`... by default something like cterm_across_log maybe

Comment: the problem is I I have no space almost left on c:/ neither other volumes to but I can try?

is this a query I will run the code you wrote?

Thank you in advance

Comment: just change `TO DISK = N'C:\Temp\cterm_across.bak'` TO `TO DISK = 'NUL:'`   for the 2 backup commands. You will have enough storage on your null device, believe me ;-)

Comment: I found a volume called "Z:\"
I have seen there made backup on this earlier(2015-02-11)
on the logfiles,
(example:)
cterm_across_log.bak

the problem now is I don't know how they made the earlier backup settings

if I do select a cterm_across I also choose \Back up Database - cterm_across I get a window with some settings but I dont know there is based on default settings or the earlier?.

Comment: Ok now the title "Can't Shrink a .LDF file" does not describe your whole problem? If you want to shrink your logilfe --> solution above. If you want to know something about earlier backups: ask the administrator (or former administrator) of this server. If this person is not available: develop your ouwn backup strategies and don't care too much about older .bak files. (or at least adive someone who can do this job)

Comment: Thank you very much CeOnSql,
actually I am the administrator at the moment so I gonna take your advices.
cheers

Comment: you're welcome! backup strategies are often discussed in the net. You will have to read some things about it but it's no rocket science.

Comment: solution to clean the log was rightclick on the DB, change recovery model to simple BAM a clean logfile then change back to full. also set a limit on the logfile :) (how many MB max)